# how to loop .attr() change on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i've been stuck for a while..

I'm trying to set up a system where the user has 3 buttons, each button brings up 1 of 3 divs. there is a check and the window thats currently open's corresponding button changes its class to change its background-color - so its easy to see what option is open.

then clicking a different button loads different content but keeps the window open - this works

clicking the same button twice closes the window and re sets button class- this works

this should be able to repeat - but it wont..

I can load the corresponding window, change its buttons class. close that window and reset the class to its original state, but when I try to open the same window again the class wont change again. it won't repeat this process..

unless you re open a different window in which case it re starts its self and works until that same point...

Super confused and cant see whats going on here..

Any help appreciated!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#findUs').click(function(){

        if($('.findUs').length){  //---.length to check if class 'findUs' exists If it dose, close dropdown and re set button-----
                    $('#findUs').attr('class','contactTitle');
                $('.infoDropdown').slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
        }
                    $('#findUs').attr('class','selectedContact');
                    $('#phoneUs').attr('class','contactTitle');
                    $('#faxUs').attr('class','contactTitle');


        $('.infoDropdown').load('global/contactOptions.php .findUs',{},function(){

            if($('.infoDropdown').is(':hidden')){
                    $('.infoDropdown').slideToggle("slow");
                }

                });

            });


//------------------------------------phone------------------------------------------
    $('#phoneUs').click(function(){

            if($('.phoneUs').length){  //---.length to check if class 'findUs' exists If it dose, close dropdown and re set button-----
                    $('#phoneUs').attr('class','contactTitle');
                $('.infoDropdown').slideToggle('slow');
                return false;
        }
                    $('#phoneUs').attr('class','selectedContact');
                    $('#findUs').attr('class','contactTitle');
                    $('#faxUs').attr('class','contactTitle');

            $('.infoDropdown').load('global/contactOptions.php .phoneUs',{},function(){

                if($('.infoDropdown').is(':hidden')){
                    $('.infoDropdown').slideToggle("slow");

                }
                });
        });
//------------------------------------Fax--------------------------------------------
    $('#faxUs').click(function(){

            if($('.faxUs').length){  //---.length to check if class 'findUs' exists If it dose, close dropdown and re set button-----
                    $('#faxUs').attr('class','contactTitle');
                $('.infoDropdown').slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
        }
                    $('#faxUs').attr('class','selectedContact');
                    $('#findUs').attr('class','contactTitle');
                    $('#phoneUs').attr('class','contactTitle');

            $('.infoDropdown').load('global/contactOptions.php .faxUs',{},function(){

                if($('.infoDropdown').is(":hidden")){
                    $('.infoDropdown').slideToggle("slow");

                }
        });
    });

});
```

===========================the main html=====================================

```
 <div align="center" >
            <span class="contactTitle" id="findUs">Find Us:</span>
            <span class="contactTitle" id="phoneUs">Phone Us:</span>
            <span class="contactTitle" id="faxUs">Fax Us:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="infoDropdown">
        </div>
```

==========================divs loaded from seporate page==============================

```
    <div class="findUs" name="findUs">
dfgdfg
        </div>

        <div  class="phoneUs" name="phoneUs">
        test
        </div>


        <div  class="faxUs" name="faxUs">
        123
        </div>
```

=====================================CSS========================================

```
<style>
.infoDropdown{
    display:none;
    height:250px;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:rgba(33,252,0,1.00);
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.contactTitle{  
    width:33%;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:30px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-top:5px;
    align-items:center;

}
.selectedContact{
    width:33%;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:30px;
    background-color:rgba(33,252,0,1.00);
    margin-top:5px;
    align-items:center; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS too please?

Comment: that should be all of it,

Comment: Seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/jye344fu/, of course the ajax calls can't be replicated easily, so that could be the issue you're having

Comment: thats acting different to what its managing in my browser -  I have it working to the point where a second click of the same button closes the open dropdown and re sets its button color, but after that it wont repeat (if you try open the same window it opens but the button wont change again for some reason ), alternating by opening and closing beteween windows works though,,, confusing :/

Comment: Try something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/jye344fu/1/

Comment: also works, thanks for the sample too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have loaded your contents once with ajax, this check is always true: `if($('.findUs').length)` And because of that you return false before ever reaching the part of your code where you change the buttons' classes.

Comment: that sounds likely, is there a way to 'un load' the item ',  or some other nifty work around that you know of? im currently trying .has() instead of .lengh for the check. dosent seem to be different..

Comment: Tried a bunch of stuff and putting .remove() in the if statement after the button .attr(), ended up being the one to go for, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!